# If a virgin birth actually disqualifies a Messianic candidate, how then should Isaiah 7:14 be interpreted?

Tags: messiah, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

Earlier today in chat, I saw [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16698584#16698584):

> Jewish identity is matrilinial. Jewish tribal lineage is patrilinial.
>
> If Jesus had no biological father, then he could not be from the tribe of Judah, as the Messiah will be. From a Jewish perspective, the irony is that being born of a virgin would not prove that one was the Messiah. On the contrary it would **invalidate** one as a messianic candidate.

Source: **anursa**, [comments on Slacktivist](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/slacktivist/2014/07/20/paint-the-grace-youre-given/), via TRiG.

It was [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16702768#16702768) by fredsbend:

> Is that an accurate depiction of Jewish thought? That is interesting.

and [affirmed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16705947#16705947) by HodofHod:

> Entirely.

Now, as a Christian, I seem to recall some prophecy about the Messiah necessarily being born of a virgin. Sure enough, I see that Isaiah 7:14 says

> 14 Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign: The **virgin** will conceive and give birth to a son, and will call him Immanuel. - [Isaiah 7:14 (NIV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah+7%3A14&version=NIV)

But wait, that's a Christian translation. Enter the JPS...

> 14 Therefore the Lord Himself shall give you a sign: behold, the **young woman** shall conceive, and bear a son, and shall call his name Immanuel. - [Isaiah 7:14 (JPS)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1007.htm)

...and Judaica Press translations.

> 14 Therefore, the Lord, of His own, shall give you a sign; behold, the **young woman** is with child, and she shall bear a son, and she shall call his name Immanuel. - [Isaiah 7:14 (Judaica Press)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15938#v=14)

(All emphasis mine.)

Okay, so the term can also be translated "young woman". So, now the question is: **why is it so significant that a *young woman* conceive and bear a son**? I'd figure that young women would be conceiving and giving birth all the time back in the old days.

---

<sup>Note: HodofHod also [pointed out in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16707435#16707435) that the "young woman" part isn't the significant thing, but the unaware naming of her child Immanuel. This would be an acceptable answer, as it does answer the question in the title about how the verse should be interpreted.</sup>

Comment: That her naming would be prophetic is mentioned by [Rashi](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15938#showrashi=true&v=14), but he doesn't specify that _that_ is what the proof is. _"and this is the sign, for she is a young girl, and she never prophesied, yet in this instance, Divine inspiration shall rest upon her. ... And some interpret that this is the sign, that she was a young girl and incapable of giving birth."_

Comment: @HodofHod: Ah, I stand corrected.

Comment: 'Twas my bad, I misread on my first pass.

Comment: Note that it is "the young woman" not "a young woman". A particular young woman was being pointed out by the prophet who was already pregnant.

Comment: Hello El'endina. I apologise if this is a redundant reply. I didn't read the entire thread. The Jewish Bible, including Isaiah, was written in Hebrew. Everything loses in translation. The English version (King James) of Scripture was a translation from a translation. The often quoted passage in Isaiah uses the Hebrew word 'almah' which translates 'young woman/girl'. The Bible uses the term 'betulah' (Virgin) elsewhere so the choice of 'almah' is meaningful. Even the KJV translates Isaiah as 'young girl' not referring to 'virgin' until the New Testament. Now I understand your questioning.....

Comment: ....if 'the' specifies a specific person, in this case,  Miriam (Mary). I am rather certain that Judaism has understood Isaiah as referring to an event that already happened or was happening at the time of its writing. Perhaps someone who is more knowledgeable can, if they already haven't done so, elaborate.

Comment: I discussed this topic pretty thoroughly at this link but I will try to tailor an answer here when the opprotunity arises: http://web.archive.org/web/20120425022737/http://www.teshuvashaminim.com/isaiah714.html

Comment: well first of all this isn't about the messiah

Comment: It is important to note that the verse did not add a qualifying adjective to the verse "young" to emphasize age. Rather the noun used to describe the person being born is itself connotes the age. Like saying "a girl will give birth".

Comment: Several Jewish biblical commentators have generally read the word "son" and "daughter" to include adoptive children. See Ibn Ezra Gen. 46:7 and Ex. 2:10 and Ḥizkuni Gen. 41:45. Joseph was the adoptive father of Jesus. Thus it is clearly analytically possible to regard Jesus as a patrilineal descendant of David if, as stated in Matthew 1:16, Joseph was.

Comment: ...instead of "a woman will give birth". The age implied by the word is more incidental. (to finish @mevaqesh's excellent point perhaps more clearly)

Comment: @JJLL Note that the word used is "the young woman" pointing to a particular young woman (Isaiah's wife according to Rashi) that the prophet is pointing to and that the king knows. See my answer.

Answer (score 18):

[Yonatan ben Uziel, Radak, Metzudat David, and Ibn Ezra](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14257&st=&pgnum=68) say that the sign is outlined in verse 15.

**Yonatan Ben Uziel says** on verse 15 and 16 the child is used as a time stamp of sorts. Basically deliverance from the two oppressing monarchy will end and the land will prosper before the child matures, and can distinguish between good and bad. It is possible that the details of the prosperity are also signs.

**Radak says** that the child from birth will only eat sweet things like curds and honey and will refuse any other foods.

**Ibn Ezra says** that it is not normal for a newborn to eat such foods, yet he will.

**Metzudat David says** that he will have a desire for these foods from birth and also adds that the boy will be able to discern between good and evil long before the age when it is normal to do so.

[מהר"י קרא](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14257&st=&pgnum=67) says that the sign was the correct identification of the gender of the baby in the currently pregnant woman's womb.

**Rashi says** that the sign was either that the young woman, who had never prophesied before, would suddenly be beset by divine inspiration, or that she was too young to be able to conceive, yet she became pregnant.

**Malbim says** that the sign was not miraculous at all, in line with the [use of sign by phylacteries](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0213.htm). The name of the lad was meant to be a sign for the people to know that God was with them.

**Gra says** that the sign was not miraculous either and was merely meant to demonstrate omniscience, predicting that when the lad would know good vs. evil, there would be an abundance of curds and honey in the land.

---

<sup>According to those who use verse 15 for the sign, mentioning 'the woman' is identifying her, either as the wife of Isaiah or of Ahaz.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

Since the question presented in the title is a very broad one, I will focus on the more specific one presented in the text while touching upon other issues.

The question asked was why it is so significant that a young woman will bear a child, implying that the issue is too mundane to be a "*sign*". Such a question, although understandable, incorrectly read the emphasis implied by the Christian understanding into the proper translation. Who is having the child is part of the sign, but not the focal point. The intent is clear when we read the fulfillment of this prophecy in the next chapter where Isaiah clearly identifies his children, including the one born in fulfillment of this prophecy, as "signs":

> Behold, I and the children whom Hashem has given me are **signs**
> (לְאתוֹת = "for signs" is plural of the word found in 7:14) and
> symbols for Israel from Hashem. (Isaiah 8:18, Stone Edition)

A careful read of Isaiah 7:14 in its context and followed up with chapter 8 will reveal many conceptual and verbal parallels allowing us to comfortably identify the child predicted in Isaiah 7:14 with the son born to Isaiah's wife in Isaiah 8:3. The sign in Isaiah 7:14 is not supernatural but symbolic, the same way the term is used in chapter 8 regarding Isaiah children. Note how Isaiah's children have symbolic names in 7:3 and 8:3 and how they only other uses in the Hebrew Bible of they symbolic name Immanuel are found in chapter 8.

Whether something validates or invalidates a "Messianic candidate" has no relevance to Isaiah 7:14 which is not a Messianic prophecy.

While it is correct to say that "the term can also be translated 'young woman'", it is important to be clear that "virgin" is not a correct translation of עלמה. Some will certainly argue this point but briefly it can be noted:

a)When virginity as a status is significant, such as legal contexts, the T'nakh uses the term בתולה.
b)In no [other] instance of עלמה in the T'nakh would *virgin* be a preferable translation.
c)The usage in Proverbs 30:18-33 is strongly suggestive that *virgin* would be an inappropriate translation.
d)The Greek text of Matthew cites this verse using the Greek word for Virgin. The Peshita (an early Christian translation into a dialect of Aramaic), uses the Aramaic cognate for בתולה, NOT עלמה, to translate the text of Matthew. (This is an original observation I am unaware of being discussed by others, See [here](http://machzikeihadas.blogspot.com/2012/11/who-is-almahs-son.html) for further discussion).

Much ink has been spilled over this passage and its interpretation but I believe that I have addressed the main point being asked and highlighted important context for understanding the best interpretation of the passage.

Comment: The child was born -- in Isaiah's time and in time to give a sign to Ahaz that his troubles with the opposing armies was resolved.  The prophecy thereafter becomes part of history and not for the future.  Rashi said that the prophetess was Isaiah's own wife and the child Emanuel was his own.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the statement was that this particular young woman (Isaiah's wife - there with them) **is pregnant** and is going to give birth naturally (within 6 - 9 months since she is not yet visibly pregnant). Even if she is not yet pregnant, Rashi says that she is about to conceive. Before the child can "tell good from evil", the threat to the kingdom will be over. It has nothing to do with messianic times. The king will see that there is nothing to worry about. He is also being chastised for trying to deny the prophesy and refuse to ask for a sign.

Since the king himself will see this, it will occur immediately.

This has nothing to do with the final redemption.
[Isaiah 7:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15938#showrashi=true&v=14)

> 14 Therefore, the Lord, of His own, shall give you a sign; behold, the
>   young woman is with child, and she shall bear a son, and she shall
>   call his name Immanuel.
>
> **Rashi:** the young woman: My wife will conceive this year. This was the
>   fourth year of Ahaz.

Before the child eats solid food, the redemption will come.

> 16 For, when the lad does not yet know to reject bad and choose good,
>   the land whose two kings you dread, shall be abandoned."
>
> **Rashi:** 
>   For, when the lad does not yet know to reject bad and choose good: the
>   land shall be abandoned by its inhabitants, [i. e.,] the land of Rezin
>   and the land of Pekah.
>
> you dread: and fear its two kings, Rezin and Pekah, for in that year
>   the king of Assyria marched on Damascus since Ahaz hired him, as it is
>   stated in the Book of II Kings (16:9): “And seized it and exiled its
>   inhabitants to Kir, and he slew Rezin,” and in that very year (ibid.
>   15: 30), “Hoshea the son of Elah revolted against Pekah the son of
>   Remaliah, and he struck him and slew him… in the twentieth year of
>   Jotham,” which was the fourth year of Ahaz.

Answer (score -4):

A couple of clarifying points:

Indeed the original Hebrew uses עַלְמָה "almah" not בְּתוּלָה "betulah", where "betulah" means "virgin" in the sense we understand it today, and the  word "almah" means "young maiden", which more precisely means "unmarried young woman". To give a parallel, in German, this term would be "Jungfrau" (literally "young woman") which is the same word used to say "virgin". Why is all this relevant? Because, remember what would be the punishment for a young, unmarried woman who became pregnant. This would not be considered an even worthy of praise or admiration. The miracle here is that the young woman became pregnant without it being sinful, hence the logical conclusion can only be that we are talking about "virgin birth". This was the logical deduction of the Jewish translators of the Septuagint (LXX) who chose the word παρθένος (from which we get the term "parthenogenesis", the scientific term for "virgin birth").

This was would have been the held interpretation of this verse until the rise of Christianity, which caused concern among the rest of Judaism, and differing interpretations were favored as a result. This can be observed with other passages (usually Messianic) in the Tanach which had a given understanding before the birth of Jesus, and remain in Christian theology but were subsequently abandoned in Rabbinical Judaism.

Secondly, the notion of Jewish "identity" (whatever that means, cf. "mihu Jehudi") being matrilineal is a novel concept, it does not come from the Tanach. Only inheritance and lineage are discussed in the Tanach, and these are patrilineal at all times... except when they are not. See for example in the book of Numbers, the daughters of Zelophehad (specifically in Chapter 36 for example) with whom the exception was given for the case when no male heirs were available. So, again, a virgin birth does not disqualify a Messianic candidate in any way, the Messiah can still receive lineage through the mother in the case where no male heir is present (ie., if she has no brothers).

Comment: I removed the section of this answer that's most blatantly about Christianity exclusively, but I think that the entire answer appears to be from the point of view of Christianity rather than Judaism and as such is not a good fit for Mi Yodeya. I recommend either [edit]ing it to present arguments from the point of view of Judaism or deleting it.

Comment: You could still include the section about Christianity as a comment here, since it does answer part of the OP's concerns in his question. It should be valid for someone to ask in a Jewish answer site questions such as "What is the Jewish view on this matter that pertains to me as a Christian?" if worded appropriately, which I believe the OP did.

Comment: Presenting the teachings of the Christian Bible is not providing a Jewish view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40228/discussion-between-isaac-moses-and-raphael-rosch).

Comment: "remember what would be the punishment for a young, unmarried woman who became pregnant" Please remind me. I know of none.

Comment: What is παρθένος and why does it show what the translator thought?

Comment: Why does what that translator thought indicate what everyone else at the time pre-Chrisitanity was thinking? That seems to just be your assertion.

Comment: "which more precisely means 'unmarried young woman'" How do you know this?

Comment: As soon as I have a chance I will edit and add some sources for definitions, etc

Comment: That's a long time without a chance to respond to my comments. Might they not have good answers?

Comment: Considering all my comments kept getting deleted, and the answer keeps getting needlessly downvoted, it's clear you guys have no interest in what I might have to say or find on the matter. *shrug* not a very welcoming place you have here for a different perspective than modern Rabbinical Judaism, even when using only the Jewish texts. If I manage to find time to devote to this on top of everything else I have to do that is more urgent, I'll come back to it. But I honestly don't see the point. Maybe convince me you are able to value my perspective and I'll put a greater effort towards that.

Comment: @DoubleAA it seems like it was not unheard of to burn unmarried women who were promiscuous.  E.g. Leviticus 21:9 and Genesis 38:24.  At least it was not looked on as a good thing.

Comment: @DoubleAA aha, found an even clearer law.  See Deuteronomy 22:20-21, where a married woman is stoned for not being a virgin on her wedding night.  The specific thing she is stoned for is have sexual relations before being married.

Comment: @yters those are all about married women

Comment: @DoubleAA Deuteronomy 22:20-21 is about a penalty administered to a married woman for something she did while unmarried.  Note the verse wording: "20 If, however, the charge is true and no proof of the young woman’s virginity can be found, 21 she shall be brought to the door of her father’s house and there the men of her town shall stone her to death. She has done an outrageous thing in Israel by being promiscuous while still in her father’s house."  She's being stoned because she was "promiscuous while still in her father's house."  I.e. nothing to do with the marriage itself.

Comment: @yters the sin was while in her father's house while betrothed. Remember back then they would betrothe and only later consummate the marriage.

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting point, but I guess the 'betrothed' is implied, since it doesn't seem to be in the explicit allegation in the verse.

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the question at all. The question supposes that virgin birth disqualifies a messianic candidate, and asks for the significance of a certain verse, given that supposition. This answer says that virgin birth does not disqualify a messianic candidate.

Comment: Also the argument from Zelophehad proves only that daughter's can inherit from fathers. It speaks not at all to whether sons can inherit from mothers. A more relevant biblical source is the Blasphemer, who is a good example of someone not inheriting their mother's lineage.

Comment: to actually answer the question and assert your stance, you would need to show that there is no significance to the verse unless that interpretation is held.

Comment: also, παρθένον and παρθένου are used in the case of Dina, right after she is lain with by Shechem. How can you possibly assert that that word means virgin universally? This whole answer is biased toward Christian belief and in bad faith.

Comment: "This was the logical deduction of the Jewish translators of the Septuagint" where do we know that the translators of the entire Septuagint were Jewish, traditional scholars? Jewish tradition (Megilla 9a) only tells us that the Torah, i.e. the 5 Books of Moses, was translated by scholars. We don't know officially who translated the Prophets and Writings; there are certain theories but nothing definite.