# Explain Isaiah 7:14

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

[Isaiah 7:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.7.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
Therefore the Lord himself will give you a sign: The virgin will conceive and give birth to a son, and will call him Immanuel ([New International Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%207:14&version=NIV) Christian Bible translation).

Who is Immanuel?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43708/170

Comment: Note that your *translation* is wrong. The translation is *the young woman who is now pregnant* Thus the sign is that a young woman who is known to the prophet is currently pregnant and will bear a son that she will call Immanu-el (Hashem is with us). Before the child is two or three years old the enemy that you are now facing will be destroyed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a virgin birth actually disqualifies a Messianic candidate, how then should Isaiah 7:14 be interpreted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43708/if-a-virgin-birth-actually-disqualifies-a-messianic-candidate-how-then-should-i)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few views in the commentaries; it really depends on the identity of the mother, who, I should note, is not considered a virgin in Judaism, as the term "עלמה" - "almah" in Hebrew means "young woman", while the Hebrew word for "virgin" is "בתולה" - "betulah", which doesn't appear in the Hebrew verse.

According to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Isaiah.7.14.3&lang2=bi), whose view is also quoted by the [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Abarbanel_on_Isaiah.7.14.2&lang2=bi), and so also say [Chomat Anach](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Chomat_Anakh_on_Isaiah.7.14.1&lang2=bi), [Ibn Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Isaiah.7.14.1&lang2=bi) and [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Isaiah.7.14.2&lang2=bi), the young woman is the wife of Isaiah and therefore Immanu-el is the son of Isaiah.

According to a second view brought by the [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Abarbanel_on_Isaiah.7.14.1&lang2=bi), [Metzudat David](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_Isaiah.7.14.2&lang2=bi) and [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Isaiah.7.14.2&lang2=bi), the young woman is the wife of King Achaz and therefore Immanu-el is the son of Achaz.

A third view mentioned by the [Abarbanel](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.14?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Abarbanel_on_Isaiah.7.14.1&lang2=bi) is that the young woman is the daughter of King Achaz and therefore Immanu-el is the grandson of Achaz.

Comment: Wait, you mean it's not referring to someone born literally hundreds of years later who couldn't possibly be giving a sign to Achaz as the verse clearly indicates the child is supposed to be doing?????????